# Spring Boot Test: Is it a good idea to have Application class per module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

My project looks like:

```
myProject/
         /persistence/pom.xml
         /persistence/src/main/java/PersistenceApplication.java
         /persistence/src/main/java/**.java

         /business/pom.xml
         /business/src/main/java/BusinessApplication.java
         /business/src/main/java/**.java

         /api/pom.xml
         /api/src/main/java/ApiApplication.java
         /api/src/main/java/**.java
```

`api` depends on `business` and `business` depends on `persistence` module. When run in production, `ApiApplication` will be the main class.

However, when running tests, I feel a requirement to add `PeristenceApplication` and `BusinessApplication` just in order to run Spring tests annotated with `@SpringBootTest`.

Is it really a requirement? I do not know a lot about `Spring-Boot` and would love to know what is the recommendation here?

How can I test my modules using `@SpringBootTest` but without requiring `*Application.java` in `persistence` and `business` module?

Thanks

Comment: Do you like to have normal unit tests or more integration tests?

Comment: more unit tests

Answer (score 3):

I believe that decoupling by layer (horizontally) is outdated approach from decade ago. I believe that project shouldn't be structured "module by layer" nor "package by layer".

It should be structured "package by feature" or "module by feature" or "microservice by feature" (vertical decoupling).

With vertical decoupling, you would cover within integration test certain feature in one package/module/microservice and your consideration would be naturally gone.

Comment: Could you please guide me to resources on that? Also, even in that scenario won't we have multiple `Application`? or are you saying have just 1  module, interested in learning this approach

Comment: Default approach is to have single `Application` configuration class per deployable unit. To find out more about "package by feature" vs "package by layer" approaches, just google for it. But these wouldn't be Spring specific resources most probably